# bootstrap pagination vue.js doesn't update function until after two clicks

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I know this is a very specific question but was wondering if someone could help me. So right now I am currently using a module from bootstrap located on this link right here:

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination/

I am currently having the trouble where I am trying to dispatch an action that is reliant on the currentPage variable.

```
<bPagination align="right" :total-rows="100" v-model="currentPage" :per-page="10" @click.native =" updatePage(currentPage); loadParticipants()"></bPagination>
```

currentPage is set to 1 as of right now like so:

```
 data() {
  return {
    currentPage: 1,
    tag: '',
    tags: [],
    ....
```

Here is a method so that I can update the page within my VueX store. So first I dispatch a method within my Vue file:

```
updatePage: function(page){ this.$store.dispatch('updatePage', page); console.log("Hit me") },
```

And then within my VueX store I use this function to commit:

```
updatePage({ commit }, updatePage) { commit('updatePage', updatePage); }
```

I then use a mutation to finally update the state data:

```
updatePage: (state, updatePage) => { state.page = updatePage; }
```

So what I want it to do is that everytime I click on a page number I get to update the page number within the vuex store immediately when you press on any of the page numbers. However, it decrements and increments a step behind everytime I click on a page number.

examples:

If I click page number 2 twice it will update the store data to page number 2

And if you click page 2 and then page 1 it will show that the store's page number is at page 2.

So it is pretty much a step behind. If anyone can push me to the right direction that would help so much. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Never mind I solved it I pretty much used @input rather than using a click event.

```
<bPagination align="right" :total-rows="100" v-model="currentPage" :per-page="10" @input =" updatePage(currentPage); loadParticipants()"></bPagination>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to figure it out! Can't find info about `@input` in a vue documentation.

Comment: @AlexanderKim, `@input` is simply equivalent to `onInput` in HTML. It specifies a handler for input events.